# How to avoid the space error in file name to be passed as single string?

Tags: excel, csv

I did an xml parsing into csv with some given template structure, 
There is one field having the file names, however the files (filenames) having the space are not getting uploaded, the solution given to us was to include the "" in file name, so that it take it as whole single string.

After parsing I need to open the csv file and remove duplicate, however on again saving the updated sheet as csv, that "" gets removed and I am not able to upload the file with the file names with spaces

Constraint : I cannot change the file name as I don't have access to the file folder, just the name

data set

```
Bengaluru   Yes     recruit.admin   19284876_CV - Aarshin Pancholi.pdf
Bengaluru   Yes     recruit.admin   18869347_MY CV.docx
Bengaluru   Yes     recruit.admin   20188470_Aayush Raj.pdf
Bengaluru   Yes     recruit.admin   9767933_ASHFAQUE KHAN.doc
Bengaluru   Yes     recruit.admin   18872361_kalam cv.doc
```

I have written the parser in Java, after parser I need to remove duplicate, 
So after removing duplicate, what necessary steps I should take to avoid this error.

Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: "*that "" gets removed*" What `""`? I don't see any `""`. It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Please show some example input, desired output, current output of what you have tried, and point out how the current output differs from the desired. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) always helps.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to append Chr(34) to each end of the string like so:

```
Chr(34) & "18869347_MY CV.docx" & Chr(34)
```